# grails select tag highlight previously set value

Tags: grails

In a form select tag, I want the current persistent value to be highlighted so the user can remember which one is the persistent value when they start selecting different choices.

```
<select>
  <option>You can pick this one...</option>
    <option>..or this one...</option>
   <option style='background:yellow'>..this one highlighted b/c you saved it last time...</option>
  </select>
```

Has anybody accomplished this in grails? Can you use the grails select tag for this or will I have to build my own tag?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `value` attribute

> value (optional) - The current selected value that evaluates equals() to true for one of the elements in the from list.

So now persistent option have `selected` attribute, and you can style it using CSS:
Example:

```
<g:select name="name" from="${1..5}" value="2"></g:select>
```

CSS:

```
option[selected]{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Close. But as soon as a user selects a different option that option becomes the highlighted one by the 'selected' css, which is useful in some instances, but not quite what I want in this case.